# How can I hide a particular function (in c++) in doxygen?

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have a class which has may functions and i want to hide a particular function. For example

```
class Test
{

   /**
    * About Function1
    *
    * @param[in]  arg1  About arg1
    * @param[in]  arg2  About arg2
    */        
    public void Function1(int arg1,char arg2);

    // Presume same documentation for this function also
    public void Function2(int,char);

    // Presume same documentation for this function also
    public void Function3(int,char);

    // Presume same documentation for this function also
    public void Function4(int,char);
}
```

Suppose I want to hide say Function2 how would I do that.

Now in the current scenario it is displaying all the four functions 
along with its documentations.

Now, I have the following attribute set in my .doxygen rule file:

`EXTRACT_ALL = YES`

Can you please suggest me something by which i can hide say Function2?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
#ifndef DOXYGEN_SHOULD_SKIP_THIS

 /* code that must be skipped by Doxygen */
 /* in your case a method/function */

#endif /* DOXYGEN_SHOULD_SKIP_THIS */
```

And in the config file, put `PREDEFINED = DOXYGEN_SHOULD_SKIP_THIS`
Make sure that `ENABLE_PREPROCESSING` is set to `YES`.

In short, you are just leveraging the preprocessor concept to work for you!

Comment: i think writing this will mesh up my

Comment: and why exactly do you think so? @Rana

Comment: thanks a lot for quick response. In my project i have around 2000 odd files and it is quite impossible to do this change though it looks very good solution. If you can suggest something by which i will put something in the documentation and then with some setting in configuration file i will be able to skip that function.Thanks

Comment: Well I can't recall any alternate solution. In our case, we document the code as soon as we write a method. So , if we're interested in preventing it from documenting, we just add this macro. But, you can club more than one methods/classes together in a single `#ifndef` to reduce some effort.

Comment: Bad idea to write C++ valid code to document your project.

Answer (score 29):

If you have `EXTRACT_PRIVATE = NO` in the config file, then you can mark any member as private to Doxygen and it will not generate documentation for that member:

```
/// @private
public void Function2(int, char);
```

Bonus question: if you wanted to use the same documentation for all four members you can do so using one of these approaches:

```
/// @{
/**
 * About Function1,2,3,4...
 */
public void Function1(int arg1, char arg2);
public void Function2(int arg1, char arg2);
public void Function3(int arg1, char arg2);
public void Function4(int arg1, char arg2);
/// @}

/**
 * About Function1,2,3,4...
 */
public void Function1(int arg1, char arg2);
/// @copydoc Function1
public void Function2(int arg1, char arg2);
/// @copydoc Function1
public void Function3(int arg1, char arg2);
/// @copydoc Function1
public void Function4(int arg1, char arg2);
```

The one using `@{`...`@}` requires the use of `DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC = YES` in the config file.

Answer (score 19):

Use cond or internal

```
/*! \cond PRIVATE */
//only documented if cond is enabled
// ...
/*! \endcond */
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I once used the [EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS](http://www.doxygen.nl/config.html#cfg_exclude_symbols) to achieve something like this.

> The EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS tag can be used to specify one or more symbol names
>    (namespaces, classes, functions, etc.) that should be excluded from the
>    output. The symbol name can be a fully qualified name, a word, or if the
>    wildcard * is used, a substring. Examples: ANamespace, AClass,
>    AClass::ANamespace, ANamespace::*Test

Unfortunately I can't completely recall nor find the config entry.

```
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS = Test::Function2*
```

Comment: i tried adding the following code like                          EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS  =  Agent::Label(int) const to skip this function from output but it didn't work where Lebel is a function with following signature void Label(int) const