# Omit functions not included in group

Tags: c++, doxygen

I have created group `exp` in doxygen comments in code below and added function `add` details. Group was created in documentation in `Modules`, but it also includes function showInt() without detailing. Why it includes it? How to omit functions that are not in group?

```
/**
 * \defgroup exp Exported utils library functions
 * \name utils API
 * \brief API provides math functions
 */

#include <iostream>

 /**
  * \ingroup exp
  * \brief Adds two numbers.
  *
  * This function takes two numbers, adds them, and then returns the result.
  *
  * \param x The first number to add.
  * \param y The second number to add.
  * \return The sum of the two numbers.
  */
int add(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}


void showInt(int value)
{
    std::cout << "value=" << value;
}
```

Doxygen version 1.8.17

doxygen -x Doxyfile

```
# Difference with default Doxyfile 1.8.17
PROJECT_NAME           = "Kyle's Doxygen Test"
PROJECT_NUMBER         = "This is just a test of Doxygen"
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
INCLUDE_GRAPH          = NO
INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH      = NO
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I hide a particular function (in c++) in doxygen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990449/how-can-i-hide-a-particular-function-in-c-in-doxygen)

Comment: Please always mention the doxygen version you used! Isn't this because the `EXTRACT_ALL=YES` that you used (so also include the output of `doxygen -x Doxyfile` in the question), see https://stackoverflow.com/q/76065544/1657886.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Skip functions without doxygen comments from documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76065544/skip-functions-without-doxygen-comments-from-documentation)

Comment: I can't understand idea of hiding functions from module. According to my understanding if  I put function into group it should be visible there, if no then - not visible.

Comment: Probably you should define which functions are in a group and which are not by means of the commands `\{` and `\}` and also use `HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS=YES`.

Comment: The [documentation of doxygen 1.9.7](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html) explicitly states that it "silently resolves the conflict for IntegerVariable by putting it into group IntVariables, because the second instance of IntegerVariable is undocumented". May be the same for 1.8.17. Can you try and add any doc comment and see if it goes away?

Comment: It might be that there is a small bug in doxygen regarding the documented group versus non documented function, I've just pushed a proposed patch, pull request https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/9994

Comment: The pull request  https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/9994 has been integarted in the master version of doxygen (1.9.7 (663c3ccdd64d4ef5e02cf6e67779c41b5b97b5fa))